# Controlling the "top half" of line-height

Tags: html, css

let me show the code for this webpage first and try to explain what I am asking.

```css
h1 {
  border: solid;
  padding-top: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
body {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
  <head>
    <title>Practice1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Sample H1 Header</h1>    
  </body>    
</html>
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to have the H1 header just barely touch the top and bottom borders that surround it.

Now, I am aware that the issue is line-height. Since I have a descending character (the "p" in "Sample H1 Header"), the bottom half is just right.  However, the top half isn't.

I don't even understand why the default line-height has that extra space on top?  I understand the bottom for descending characters like "p" and "q", but what characters require the extra space on the top?  So understanding this, I guess, is my first question.

The second question is how to change the top half in my example so that the "Sample H1 Header" just barely touches the border I defined.  I can change the h1 css to line-height: .7; and that will give me what I am looking for....expect then my poor "p" is sticking outside.  So I want to keep the line-height on the bottom half at the default, but change it just on the top.  In other words, how can I control the top and bottom half portion of line-height independent of each other?

I did find one solution.  That's using the following in combination with the H1 header.

```
line-height: .7;
padding-bottom: 7px;
```

That gives me the look I am accomplishing.  The problem with that solution, though, is I need to seem to adjust it manually if I decide to later change font-families and sizes.  I would like something more automatic that I can simply apply whenever I need it without having to measure and modify for each case.  Any ideas?

Or is there a way I can just turn "off" the top half of line height or have it adjust automatically to the tallest capital letter of the font and size I am using?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is like an essay. I haven't read it yet. But try to shorten it!

Comment: Mention your question in bold or highlight your main question and your expected output,

Answer (score 2):

as we know every font has their own vertical space. So if you want only vertical space of font inside the border then you have to make line-height same as the font-size.

```
h1 {
 line-height: 36px;
 font-size: 36px;
}
```

Some font have more vertical space at top so you have to manage that space using padding as required.

Answer (score 1):

Every font has their own vertical space which is exactly define the line height so the solution which you have is the best for the case .